# Math and change field color

Tags: python, django-admin

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 127)
description = models.TextField()
code = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
lot_no = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
inventory = models.IntegerField()
commited = models.IntegerField()
reorder = models.IntegerField()
created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
comment_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
comment_txt = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.code + " - " + self.name + " - " + self.lot_no + " - " + str(self.created_date)

@property
def available(self):
    return self.inventory - self.commited
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from CMS.Inventory.models import Product

class padmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
search_fields=['name', 'description', 'code', 'lot_no' ]
admin.site.register(Product, padmin)
```

I am trying to make a field that is non editable but viewable in the django product class that does the math thats in the @property field.  I am also trying to do a comparison of available to reorder such that if reorder is less than available the reorder field will become red showing that you needed to order more.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def colored_available(self):
    if self.reorder < self.available:
       return self.reorder
    return '<span style="color: red;">%d</span>' % self.reorder

colored_available.allow_tags = True
colored_available.short_description = "Available"
```

And this to your model admin (padmin):

```
list_display = ('name', 'colored_available') # add more fields to be displayed in the list of products
readonly_fields = ('colored_available',)
```